# Cookies not clearing after closing browser in Mac OS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome

My web application which is build in MVC4 is clearing cookies when it opening in chorme in windows. But the same application is not clearing cookies when it run in MAC OS. IE is working fine as expected but in chrome its not clearing. Can anybody please tell me how its happening?

Answer (score 0):

Under MAC OS you have no permission to clear or delete a Cookie. You can reset a cookie with null values. But the only way to kill a cookie is over user interaction.